# C# WPF Memory leak when Window has a TabControl with a TabItem (or delayed memory reclaim?)

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, tabcontrol, tabitem

I experienced what appears to be a very obvious memory leak in an application that would open a settings window containing a TabControl with a number of TabItems. Initially believing that one of the user controls shown must be the culprit I commented out a bunch of things, finally getting out JetBrains dotMemory and making a demo-program.

**The issue (I think)**

When a Window contains a TabControl with at least one TabItem, when the window is closed, the Window-object still exists. If there are no TabItems in the TabControl, the Window-object is destroyed immediately (as expected).

**Retention**

According to dotMemory the 'Retention' is from WindowAutomationPeer(._owner), from TabControlAutomationPeer(._parent), from TabItemAutomationPeer(._parent), from ElementProxy(._peer) and then it says "RefCounted handle" at the bottom.

**Reproduction**

Create a new C# WPF application (Target framework: .NET Framework 4.7.2), named "TabsInWindows"

Add a button to MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="TabsInWindows.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open tab window" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Create a new Window, "TabsWindow" with a TabControl and a TabItem:

```
<Window x:Class="TabsInWindows.TabsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TabsWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="Subject">
            <TabItem></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Make the button in MainWindow open a new TabWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TabsWindow.Open(this);
        TabsWindow w = new TabsWindow();
        w.Show();
    }
}
```

Start the application. Every time you press the button a new window is created, but the TabItem (?) and therefore the TabWindow remains when the window is closed. (Repeat any number of times)

**How to fix?**

My issue is that in my actual application all contents of all tabs appears to be retained in memory, causing a significant memory leak.

I have tried, in the demo application, to do a number of things to avoid the hanging objects; Setting content of Grid to null. Clearing the Items in TabControl (Subject). Clearing the Children of the Grid.
None of it has worked.

I cannot work out what the 'AutomationPeer'-objects are or what the ElementProxy is created by and why it won't die.

If anyone can tell me how to get around this issue, or can shed some light on what ElementProxy is and why it is hanging around, it would be most helpful.

**While writing this**, I did keep dotMemory running with the test app and a while after having done anything last, the objects did appear to have been removed....

Which then raises the question: How long can I expect an object to be visible in memory, with references, before it is removed?

**In an actual project**

I then tried something similar in an actual project, ensuring that non of our own controls were directly linked to SettingsWindow (I'm not ruling out that I have a memory/reference issue in one of our controls, so any control listed directly in "Key Retention Paths" have been commented out).
I am left with "3 unique branches", one being an 'EffectiveValueEntry[40]' from out own extension of a ListBox, the other two are 'EffectiveValueEntry' ([19] and [22] respectively), both from a TextBlock, from TextBlockAutomationPeer[4], List, ListBoxItemAutomationPeer, ElementProxy.

After about ten minutes of doing nothing, the SettingsWindow was still there, but the "Key Retention Paths" has changed, and the "20 unique branches" are all EffectiveValueEntry ([32] on the first, [42] on the rest), TextBox, TextEditor, but now "F-Reachable Queue" is in the bottom of the list.

After about ten minutes more, the SettingsWindow was finally gone.

I then opened the settings window a few times again, and a minute after closing the last, only the 'TextBox'-references where left and a forced Garbage Collection later (using the button in dotMemory), the object references are gone.

**What to believe?**

So apparently, if I wait long enough 'magic' will happen - but this is a computer - not a magic-box!

Can anyone enlighten me on why some objects will appear in memory longer, but eventually be removed? How long should I expect such objects to lay about?

I would also like a way to prevent these 'ghost' objects from the TabItems, there should be no reason for them to take up memory if they will eventually be removed anyways...
You see, I discovered this while doing performance testing of some UI components in the SettingsWindow, and repeated tests took longer and longer as more memory was used, so simply waiting for the references to go away is not a very good option.

And if you are unable to help; thank you for taking the time to read my wall of text...

Comment: What you see there is evidence of the window not clearing out it's references (resources) in time and being qualified for later, gen 2, garbage collection. GC should collect your window when it needs to acquire more memory, as you said that the window is later collected, means that, sooner or later, it will be gone.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Is there a way to force it to clean up? Perhaps something I can do OnClosed ?

Comment: I know this is not the best solution but you could try to call `GC.Collect();` after you're done with it, but not on closed event. I can't guarantee that this will help or it will collect the objects but it is worth a try. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#generations) link for garbage collection.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I doubt it would make a difference as it has no to little effect when pressing that button in the interface. I have tried going through all the tabs on close and removing the content, this appears to help some of the contained objects to be reclaimed faster. An empty TabItem at least takes up less memory than also having the contained object.

Comment: Why do you care how soon the memory is reclaimed?

Comment: @MikeNakis Because the tab control is in my settings window. This window is opened and closed quite frequently in some situations, and from what I can tell the memory usage keeps growing. Our applications are generally long running (sometimes months without restarting), and we know from experience that memory leaks just don't help. For some applications physical machinery will stop, if the PC/application slows down. I have no reason to think this type of leak will not also cause such issues.

Comment: That's not how it works.  Total memory usage is absolutely irrelevant in a garbage-collected system.  Only the memory allocations that survive garbage collection are relevant.  You cannot be speaking of memory leaks when the memory gets eventually reclaimed.  So, stop worrying.

Comment: @MikeNakis That might not be how it works, but seeing as we have previously had memory leaks, this is not making it any easier to check whether leaks are actually happening as I have to have my PC standing idle for up to half an hour before I can check if there might be a memory issue.
Also, seeing as this memory DOES survive garbage collection, how would you define if something is or is not a memory leak?

Comment: you did not previously indicate that you have memory allocations that survive garbage collection.  You only spoke of memory allocations that do not get reclaimed ***soon***.  I explained that soon is irrelevant.  Now you are saying that the problem is not how soon the memory gets reclaimed, it is that it never gets reclaimed.  So, I have nothing to say about that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the owner of the TabWindow's

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       TabsWindow w = new TabsWindow();
       w.Owner = this;
       w.Show();
}
```

Comment: Setting the owner makes no difference.